# How to solve multiple borrows compilation error

Tags: rust

I'm writing a toy SQL database to both learn Rust and about databases (I'm translating the code from a tutorial written in C). I'm having trouble getting the following code to compile, due to borrow checker errors:

```rust
struct Pager {
    pages: [Option<Box<[u8; PAGE_SIZE]>>; TABLE_MAX_PAGES]
}

impl Pager {
    fn new() -> Self {
        const INIT: Option<Box<[u8; PAGE_SIZE]>> = None;
        Self {
            pages: [INIT; TABLE_MAX_PAGES],
        }
    }

    fn get_page(&mut self, page_num: usize) -> &mut [u8] {
        // returns a page, creating a new one if necessary
        let page = Box::new([0u8; PAGE_SIZE]);
        self.pages[0].replace(page);

        &mut self.pages[page_num].as_mut().unwrap()[..]
    }
}

struct Table {
    pager: Pager,
    num_rows: usize,
}

impl Table {
    fn new() -> Self { 
        Self { pager: Pager::new(), num_rows: 0 }
    }

    fn cursor_value(&mut self, cursor: &Cursor) -> &mut [u8] { 
        let row_num = cursor.row_num;
        let page_num: usize = row_num / ROWS_PER_PAGE;

        let byte_offset = (row_num % ROWS_PER_PAGE) * ROW_SIZE;

        let page = self.pager.get_page(page_num);
        &mut page[byte_offset..byte_offset+ROW_SIZE]
    }
}

struct Cursor<'a> {
    table: &'a Table,
    row_num: usize,
    end_of_table: bool,
}

impl <'a> Cursor<'a> {
    fn table_end(table: &'a Table) -> Self { 
        Self { table, row_num: table.num_rows, end_of_table: true }
    }

    fn advance(&mut self) {
        self.row_num += 1;
        if self.row_num >= self.table.num_rows {
            self.end_of_table = true;
        }
    }
}

fn execute_insert(table: &mut Table) {
    let cursor = Cursor::table_end(&table);
    let _buf = table.cursor_value(&cursor);
    // here we insert new row into the table by writing into _buf
    // ...
}
```

The problem is that I'm borrowing the table twice inside the `execute_insert` function: once with a mutable reference (for `cursor_value` method) and once with an immutable one (for `table_end` method):

```
28 |     let cursor = Cursor::table_end(&table);
   |                                    ------ immutable borrow occurs here
29 |     let buf = table.cursor_value(&cursor);
   |               ^^^^^^------------^^^^^^^^^
   |               |     |
   |               |     immutable borrow later used by call
   |               mutable borrow occurs here
```

Is there a way I can achieve this in Rust, or should I maybe use a different design for those data structures?

Comment: Why does `Cursor` need a reference back to `Table` when the `cursor_value` function works the other way around, `Table` to `Cursor`? Removing that reference could solve your issue.

Comment: You probably don't need a cursor, in fact, more idiomatic Rust would be to [`impl IterMut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/struct.IterMut.html) instead.

Comment: This is an artifact of me trying to simplify the code example as much as I can. In the actual code Cursor needs a reference to Table to calculate some of its fields based on stuff like the number of rows in the table.

Comment: @tadman thanks for pointing IterMut to me, I'll check it out. I think that cursor abstraction is quite important in a design of an sql database, and even if it's very simple in its current form it will become much more advanced when the backing storage will change to a B-tree and I'll need to support deletes, updates and so on, so my feeling is that I should keep it as it is in the tutorial, if it's possible to do in Rust.

Comment: I have the feeling that you minimized the example too much. We need to discuss you actual code, to see what you can change. With this snippet, all we can say that can apply to your actual code is "no, you cannot hold both reference to the table in the cursor and modify the table with a cursor" (except with `Rc`, which you probably don't want to use) which isn't very helpful.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Good point. I have updated the example, now it contains the Pager abstraction which I use to get the table's data and also included the full code of the cursor_value method. I put some simplified code into the get_page method of the Pager, to illustrate that it modifies its data.

Comment: I don't see that `Cursor` needs to hold a reference to `Table` in your code.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I have added a bit more implementation to the `Cursor` struct, which might illustrate why it needs a reference to `Table`. For example, you can use the `advance_cursor` method and the `end_of_table` to iterate over all rows in the table in a while loop.

Comment: I don't think this problem is solvable without rethinking your data structures. Ownership in Rust always has to be a tree, and yours is a circle. For example: Your `Cursor::advance` could take a `table`. Or your `Cursor` could store a `&mut table`, and then do `cursor.value()` instead of `table.cursor_value()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is conceptually unsound. It's possible that multiple cursors exist, and if one cursor does `table.cursor_value(&cursor)`, then the `self.table.num_rows` changes for the other cursor, and `end_of_table` might be true, although the cursor is not at the end.

This is why this code fails to compile: It's guaranteed in Rust that as long as you hold an immutable reference to something (like `self.table` in `Cursor`), then its value **will not change**. Therefore you won't ever be able to modify the table as long as you reference it immutably in `Cursor` and don't use inner mutability via `Rc<RefCell>` or similar.

The solution is simple to me: you only want one cursor at a time anyway (that's at least my assumption), so simply reference `self.table` via a `&mut` reference. Then you don't need `Table::cursor_value()` at all, you can directly do it from `Cursor::value()`.

Like this:

```
const ROWS_PER_PAGE: usize = 64;
const ROW_SIZE: usize = 128;
const PAGE_SIZE: usize = ROW_SIZE * ROWS_PER_PAGE;
const TABLE_MAX_PAGES: usize = 32;

struct Pager {
    pages: [Option<Box<[u8; PAGE_SIZE]>>; TABLE_MAX_PAGES],
}

impl Pager {
    fn new() -> Self {
        const INIT: Option<Box<[u8; PAGE_SIZE]>> = None;
        Self {
            pages: [INIT; TABLE_MAX_PAGES],
        }
    }

    fn get_page(&mut self, page_num: usize) -> &mut [u8] {
        // returns a page, creating a new one if necessary
        let page = Box::new([0u8; PAGE_SIZE]);
        self.pages[0].replace(page);

        &mut self.pages[page_num].as_mut().unwrap()[..]
    }
}

struct Table {
    pager: Pager,
    num_rows: usize,
}

impl Table {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            pager: Pager::new(),
            num_rows: 0,
        }
    }

    fn get_row(&mut self, row_num: usize) -> &mut [u8] {
        let page_num: usize = row_num / ROWS_PER_PAGE;

        let byte_offset = (row_num % ROWS_PER_PAGE) * ROW_SIZE;

        let page = self.pager.get_page(page_num);
        &mut page[byte_offset..byte_offset + ROW_SIZE]
    }
}

struct Cursor<'a> {
    table: &'a mut Table,
    row_num: usize,
    end_of_table: bool,
}

impl<'a> Cursor<'a> {
    fn table_end(table: &'a mut Table) -> Self {
        let row_num = table.num_rows;
        Self {
            table,
            row_num,
            end_of_table: true,
        }
    }

    fn advance(&mut self) {
        self.row_num += 1;
        if self.row_num >= self.table.num_rows {
            self.end_of_table = true;
        }
    }

    fn value(&mut self) -> &mut [u8] {
        self.table.get_row(self.row_num)
    }
}

fn execute_insert(table: &mut Table) {
    let mut cursor = Cursor::table_end(table);
    let _buf = cursor.value();
    // here we insert new row into the table by writing into _buf
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Your solution seems so simple, now that I've seen it, and I've come to realize that it's probably closer to the original idea in the C tutorial than what I've done originally. I've refactored the code a little, by moving the implementation of the `get_row` method into the `Cursor`'s `get_value` method and the code feels much better now. Thanks a lot!